# Maximum minimum of $x^2$ on the open interval $-1<x<1$

Tags: maximum-principle

The question goes like this:

Does the function $f(x)=x^2$ have a maximum on the open interval $(-1,1)$ ? And a minimum? Explain

Not exactly sure how to give a proper answer really. For me it makes sense that it has a minimum but not a maximum since the interval is open $(1,1)$ instead of closed $[1,1]$. Still, I really do not know how to explain it in mathematical language based upon some mathematical principle...does it also have to do with the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $f\bigl((-1,1)\bigr)=[0,1)$ follows that $f$ has a minimum but no maximum on $(-1,1)$.

Edit: And yes, it follows from the IVT as it states that the image of an interval under a continuous function itself is an interval.

Answer (score 0):

the Minimum Min(0,0) lies in the interval $(-1,1)$ and annsupremum can be found by $\lim_{x -> \pm 1}x^2$